# Link HTTPS javascript file into HTTP site

Tags: javascript, http, https

I have just installed my SSL certificate so I can use the HTTPS protocol to access my site. I don't want the entire site to be HTTPS but only the login panel and register page. The register page is easy to implement as HTTPS but the login panel is JavaScript code that uses AJAX to identify the user. How can I make that script file be HTTPS (and call the PHP file thought HTTPS, too)? Does it make sense? Can I add the script file in the header of the HTML file like this: `<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.mysite.com/js/login.js"></script>`?
Thanks!

Comment: in my opinion it has no logic to work like that, if you use https:// to one or two pages, why not use to the whole website?!

Comment: Because I embed other external scripts that have no alternative for HTTPS sites, which means that if I embed an HTTP script into my HTTPS site, I will get security warnings from the browser about the site being partially secure (not fully HTTPS)

Comment: Those warnings aren't without reason, would it be possible to host those scripts on your own server?

Comment: Furthermore, you don't have to get the javascript file from a secure location, as long as you're posting the login information to a secure location using https? However, I'm wondering if the session-cookie will be accepted on a non-https URL if it is set by a https location

Comment: Non-secure login pages that post to secure login are not secure. For example, the JS and HTML present on a hypothetical HTTP login page could be altered to submit the data to an attacker's chosen endpoint rather than the ostensibly secure path.